# Наследование ссылок из src при обертке с помощью wrap

Tags: jquery, наследование, href

Доброе время суток, имеется код изображения:

```
<img src="../../images/uploads/0bd5.jpg" class="bbcode-image">
```

из него требуется создать ссылку вида:

```
<a href="../../images/uploads/0bd5.jpg" target="_blank" rel="shadowbox"><img src="../../images/uploads/0bd5.jpg" class="bbcode-image"></a>
```

поколдовав с jQuery получился код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bbcode-image").wrap('<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="shadowbox"></a>');
```

});
`

но вот собственно и проблема: что прописать в href="#" чтобы в него вместо #  автоматически вставлялась ссылка с

```
src="../../images/uploads/0bd5.jpg"
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$(".bbcode-image").wrap(function(){
   return '<a href="' + $(this).attr("src") + '" target="_blank" rel="shadowbox"></a>';
});
```

Или так:

```
$(".bbcode-image").wrap(function(){
   return '<a href="' + this.src + '" target="_blank" rel="shadowbox"></a>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Оба кода работоспособны, благодарю за помощь, но по видимому у меня на сайте где-то ошибка и функции не стартовали. Проблема решилась добавлением:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

в итоге получился такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bbcode-image").wrap(function(){
   return '<a href="' + this.src + '" target="_blank" rel="shadowbox"></a>';
    });});
```